# Angular: Is there a way to retrieve the query parameter value without knowing the key name?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am setting the `queryParams` in one component dynamically and want to retrieve them in another component. I can not use the `queryParams['key']` since I do not know the value of `key`. So how can I retrieve the `queryParams` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using queryParamMap ,

```
Object.keys(queryParamMap).forEach((key) => { 
/* what you want to do goes here*/ 
}
```

This gets all keys and you can process them in forEach and get values accordingly